# Migration from Basic Authentication to OAuth2.0 Authentication in RestTemplate

Tags: oauth, basic-authentication, resttemplate

I have an existing application using `RestTemplate` Basic Authentication. It needs to be migrated to `RestTemplate` `OAuth2.0` with minimal regressions. Is there any existing example in Java?

Did some research, but no results. Please guide me.